# Paste without messing up indentation in insert mode

Tags: cut-copy-paste, neovim

I use <kbd>Ctrl-R</kbd> to paste in vim when I am in insert mode, but this , more often than, not messes up the inentation and I have to indent it manually or use <kbd>=</kbd>. All this makes <kbd>Ctrl-R</kbd> same as going to normal mode and use <kbd>]p</kbd> if not less efficient. Any way to paste while in insert mode without messing up indentation ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [`:help i_CTRL-R_CTRL-P`](https://neovim.io/doc/user/insert.html#i_CTRL-R_CTRL-P):

```
CTRL-R CTRL-P {0-9a-z"%#*+/:.-=}            *i_CTRL-R_CTRL-P*
    Insert the contents of a register literally and fix the
    indent, like |[<MiddleMouse>|.
    Does not replace characters!
    The '.' register (last inserted text) is still inserted as
    typed.
```

Comment: The way vim fixes indentation is often not so good.